# Model Selection to Predict a Multi-Category Score

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I’m hoping for some advice on prediction model selection. All thoughts much appreciated. Details below.

•   I score people in a database based on analysis of 4 categories.

•   For each category a person gets a score of 1 to 5.

•   So, each person has a combined 4-digit score of, for example, 1111, 4123 or 2341....etc.

•       And there are 5^4 = 625 possible scores.

•   I have these 4-digit scores calculated for each person for each month over the past 2 years.

•   I want to use the past 24 months of scores to try and predict the 4-digit score that people will have next month.

In each category if someone moves, a lot of the time it will be in a +/-1 step. But it is very possible for people to move more than that in one month, for example go from a 1 to a 5 in one month.

2 of the categories may be impacted by monthly seasonality so a model that can work with this is beneficial.

So, I‘m trying to predict a score made up of 4 categories, based on previous scores. Can provide further info if needed.

Any thoughts or advice is welcome!

My experience is in logistic regression and various tree based methods & SVMs for classification. But the models I've used won't solve this multi-classification or multi-category score problem.

I've read around to get some pointers. But would love to be able to pick a few brains on this.